# Time zone changes database

Tags: timezone

I have stock trading portal and historical prices are kept in local time (say New York, London, Kiev time). But all trades are kept in Moscow time.

Is it possible to get historical timeshifts between Moscow and local markets for a reasonable period - say 10 years back from now?

Comment: Your OS should already know this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database. You should clarify your question which tools/software you are using and what you have tried.

Comment: That's excatly what I need! Thanks!